# "What is" vs "What does"

Tags: grammar

If the answer is:
***She does not like to drink coffee***.

Which question is correct?

> - What doesn't she like to drink?

or:

> - What is she doesn't like to drink?

Comment: The second isn’t grammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably worth taking a look at your answer sentence before looking at questions that correspond to it.

There is a traditional game that children play, called "[he loves me/he loves me not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_loves_me..._he_loves_me_not)", where find the answer to a question by saying these two sentences alternately while pulling the petals from a flower. The answer is the sentence that you say as you pull off the last petal.

In medieval English (for example in Shakespeare's plays), you negate a sentence by adding "not" after the main verb, for example in this is statement and negative:

> he loves me - *statement*
>   he loves me **not** - *negated statement*

In modern English, we still add **not** after the main verb if the main verb is **is**:

> he is busy - *statement*
>   he is **not** busy - *negated statement*

For all other verbs, you [negate a sentence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/negation) by putting **not** after the auxiliary verb in the sentence:

> he must love me - *statement*
>   he must **not** love me - *negated statement*

If there is no auxiliary verb, you change the verb to an infinitive and add **does** as an auxiliary verb, then add **not** after it:

> he loves me -*statement*
>   he **does not** love me - *negated statement*

Here's how that applies to your sentence:

> She likes to drink coffee - *statement*
>   She **does not** like to drink coffee - *negated statement*

So, your original sentence is simply a negated statement. **does not** isn't necessarily part of the question: it's there because the question is answered in the negative.

Similarly, when you ask a question, you invert the subject and auxiliary verb:

> She must drink coffee - *statement*
>   Must she drink coffee? - *question*

and if there is no auxiliary verb, you convert the verb to an infinitive, add **does**, then invert it:

> She likes to drink coffee - *statement*
>   **Does she** like to drink coffee? - *question*

The question above could be answered by your sentence.

If you are fairly certain that she doesn't like coffee, you could also ask the question in the negative:

> **Doesn't she** like to drink coffee? - *negative question*

If you want to know what she likes to drink, you use the question-word **what** followed by an inversion:

> What **does she** like to drink? - *question*

If you know that she doesn't like to drink something, but you don't know what it is,

> What **doesn't she** like to drink? - *negative question*

Alternatively you could ask:

> What **is it** that she **doesn't** like to drink? - *positive question about a negative statement*

So, there are at least four questions that could get your sentence as an answer:

> **Does she** like to drink coffee?
>   **Doesn't she** like to drink coffee?
>   What **doesn't she** like to drink?
>   What **is it** that she **doesn't** like to drink?

Your first question is therefore grammatically correct, but it is not the only possible question.

Answer (score 2):

> What doesn't she like to drink?

This is grammatical, although this phrasing can also be a somewhat sarcastic way of saying that she likes to drink anything. (For example, someone might ask me, “What does your son Ted like to eat for lunch?” and I might answer, “What *doesn’t* he like to eat?” meaning that Ted isn’t a picky eater, and will eat almost anything.)

> <strike>What is she doesn't like to drink?</strike>

This one is not grammatical, although we could add a couple words and transform it into a grammatical question giving the answer you want:

> What is the drink that she doesn’t like?

That’s an unusual phrasing, though, and I wouldn’t expect to hear a question formed like that very often. Perhaps if you had told me, “Linda doesn’t like coffee,” and some time later I remembered you had told me something, but couldn’t remember which drink she didn’t like, then I might ask you:

> “What did you say Linda didn’t like to drink?"